How to set showpreview to true when using htmlembed in a custom ckeditor5 plugin?
I'm creating a custom Ckeditor5 plugin that grabs a snippet of javascript from an api and displays it. Right now when it displays in the ckeditor5 it is showing the code and not a preview of the embeded content.
In the documentation it says you can set showPreview = true however I cant find any information on how to do it within the context of the execute method.
from the documentation:
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        plugins: [ HtmlEmbed, /* ... */ ],
        toolbar: [ 'htmlEmbed', /* ... */ ],
        htmlEmbed: {
            showPreviews: true,
            sanitizeHtml: ( inputHtml ) => {
                // Strip unsafe elements and attributes, for example:
                // the `<script>` elements and `on*` attributes.
                const outputHtml = sanitize( inputHtml );

                return {
                    html: outputHtml,
                    // true or false depending on whether the sanitizer stripped anything.
                    hasChanged: true
                };
            }
        }
    } )
    .then( /* ... */ )
    .catch( /* ... */ );

this is how I am using it within my custom plugin:
export default class InsertNameCoachCommand extends Command {
execute() {
  const userInput = prompt("Please enter the username:");

  if (userInput) {
    const requestUrl = `/api/namecoach/data?  username=${encodeURIComponent(userInput)}`;

    fetch(requestUrl)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network Response Error');
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        if (data) {
          this.editor.execute('htmlEmbed', data.embed_image);
        } else {
          console.error("Error:", data.error);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Failed to fetch data:", error);
      });
    }
  }
}

I have tried this from the documentation for the execute command to no avail
this.editor.commands.get('htmlEmbed','showPreviews:true').execute(data.embed_image);

